# mysql average temperature of every day in a period

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with date and max temperature.

I'm trying to find the average max temperature of each day of the year given a period of years. 
Ex. The average of tmax for 01-01 in the period of 1980 and 2013.

With the following query I found Tmax ordered as I want, but I can't find a way to group by each day.

```
$resultat = mysql_query ("SELECT data, Tmax FROM $estacio WHERE data between '1980-01-01' and '2013-12-31' group by day(data),year(data);");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultat)) { 
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>',$row[0],'</td><td>',$row[1],'</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
    }
```

Comment: So why don`t you use `AVG(Tmax)`

Comment: I've tried but the result is not correct. I can get the average I want for a single day with a loop between the first and the last year. I need the same for the whole year.

Comment: SELECT AVG(Tmax) FROM $estacio WHERE data between '1980-01-01' and '2013-12-31' group by date(data) should help.....mysql is deprecated use mysqli or PDO instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the average max temperatures per day over multiple years. Each row shows the day and month and the average temperature in the given period for that day.

```
SELECT
  DAY(data),
  MONTH(data),
  AVG(Tmax)
FROM $estacio 
WHERE data BETWEEN '1980-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'
GROUP BY DAY(data), MONTH(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

For finding the average surely you would need to use the function `AVG()`.

Use it like

```
SELECT
DAY(data)
MONTH(data),
  AVG(Tmax)
FROM $estacio 
WHERE data BETWEEN '1980-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'
GROUP BY DAY(data), MONTH(data);
```